# Python: Detect duplicate and consecutive numbers

Tags: python

Instructions:
"Create a python program to detect if a number of 10 digits is valid. The number should have 10 digits, it can't contain the number "0" and can't contain duplicate consecutive numbers."

...I am using the append to request the 10 numbers and validating that they are different of 0, but I still dont know how to see if the numbers are consecutive.

This is what I have so far:

```
list=[]
for num in range (1,10): #Request 10 numbers (it can't be zero)
    num=int (input("Add 10 digits:"))
    list.append (num)
    while num != 0:
        print ("The number is valid.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Convert the number to a string using the *str()* function
- Use the *len()* function to validate the length
- Use the in-operator to see validate whether the number contains zero
- Use `zip(s, s[1:])` as a simple way to bring consecutive characters together

Comment: One more hint:

**determine how and when to apply your validity test**

In other words, if you want to run your validity test on an input number from user input, then `num=int(input("Add 10 digits:"))` is a good way to get user input, but you should not have that code inside of your `for` loop based on the `range (1,10)`.  You can use a while loop like this:
`while (len(num) != 10 and '0' not in num):` [newline]
`num = input("Input 10 digit number: ")`
If you want to generate all possible valid numbers, this is an entirely more complex problem, but could begin with that `range (1,10)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `while` because `for` will end you loop before finished if there duplicate digit

```
mylist=[]
while len(mylist) < 10: #Request 10 numbers (it can't be zero)
    mylistLength = str(len(mylist))
    num=int(input("Add 10 digits [" + mylistLength +"]: "))
    if num not in mylist:
      mylist.append(num)
    else:
      num=int(input("Digit exist, try other: "))
    if len(mylist) == 10:
        print("The number is valid.")

print(mylist)
```